# disabled touch on mobile owl carousel

Tags: jquery

this is in my script

```
$("#owl-caro").owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    itemsDesktopSmall:[979,4]

});
```

but I want to add an option, touchDrag : false when it's mobile. Should I rewrite like this?

```
$("#owl-caro").owlCarousel({
    touchDrag:  false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add comma to last attribute and add yours:

```
$("#owl-caro").owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    itemsDesktopSmall:[979,4],
    touchDrag:  false
});
```